# How to insert data from another table into an existing table, with an autoincrementing id?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-schema

I have two massive tables, with a lot of duplicated values, and I just created a new database schema. Now, I have to extract all the data to insert them in the new table.

However, I'm facing a problem : what I'm trying to do, is to extract one column (for the moment) from one of the big table, and to insert it inside the table **Town(id_town,town_name)**, with id_town being an autoincrementing Primary Key, as :

```
ALTER TABLE Town
ADD COLUMN id_town SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

I did this, so I can extract all the towns and put everyone of them with their specific ID. (if you have a better solution, I'll take it by the way!)

So, I'm trying to extract the data, but it doesn't work :

```
INSERT INTO town
SELECT DISTINCT location
FROM old_table1
```

The displayed error tells me it's awaiting for the value of id_town ; but, from what I understood of incrementing values, it should generate itself.

What am I doing wrong?

---

The other problem I'm meeting : I guess I kinda have the right syntax to extract one column from the old table to put it in the new one, but I don't really know how I'm supposed to extract specific columns from one of the two old tables, and put them in only some columns of the new table :

I have a table, for example, that has 6 columns (including the autoincrementing id), 3 of them coming from old_table1, 2 of them from old_table2. How am I supposed to extract the data?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO town (town_name)
SELECT DISTINCT location
FROM old_table1
```

If you are not providing values for all columns, then you should explicitly specify the columns you are inserting into

Comment: Yep, it is working, thanks a lot ! Now I'm trying to understand how to make my system work, because I'm now trying to use a Star Schema, and that's the first time I'm trying that !